Encrypt in Golang Decrypt in JavaScript
I am trying to create an encryption using GoLang
func Encrypt(text string) (string,error) {
secretKey := "XM1IyN4ZOJfcbDH3Md7m7XmNGGjtXMJw"
    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(secretKey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return "", err
    }
    plainText := []byte(text)
    iv := []byte("7061737323313233")
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    cipherText := make([]byte, len(plainText))
    cfb.XORKeyStream(cipherText, plainText)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(cipherText), nil
}

And then Decrypt it in Javascript
  var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('XM1IyN4ZOJfcbDH3Md7m7XmNGGjtXMJw');
  var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
  
  var encryptedData = "7sEPYaArhx0YGAqDzYHvhZFOCBvmbzAmZBCp7AwrRCiYPGlS9y+zA18qj9afqeEm00qvGBRkQA24MwK9jxStpkaS8VvGs78VyG1vt2CsEIagXFiokdj6AnuwrYt2kUp7Xex3qurYr3B4bl2jlPeA6kzB0XeG07vB5teblvvfkRgwQ3Mvph+soCPJ9byTqycdjqa4qpgWnvN3KpMWu7cmYvOITOXhv0K88SLvVKg4VRzpxJ3DtUmIF2fm8M6jQ1I6uIvNFVV3WV6pp8MDq31/xe0vFDujNBp/RYiYyB456pnj0gHPlvlVS6SblTZc11wsCU8GPClnlCyZkeIICKRKCEGyfh7tQLMRMRlcjmWDRdcMx9zFDRroNeHYeG1+b/H4TOgVQG1iqkM9O8/4TD1m2BvYe8ZH7248ceqZucFfSa0rigLZE1K1B/QnQGOfpxuTJjMkw7qdmnm4v6yYOBJPNZa1L5zo9L/RWpkSYzRcjus5wHzuyi8a";
  
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData, key, {
    keySize: 256 / 8,
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

var decryptedText = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("Decrypted Text:", CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted));

The problem is that the return string in Javascript is only upto 125 characters long, and sometimes when the text is too short it does not decrypt, is there something wrong with the configs in my decryption?
I already tried using other encryption/decryption mode but it seems it does not work either.

The CFB mode is a stream cipher mode and does not require padding. On the Go side there is no padding, on the CryptoJS side there is. Disable the padding in the CryptoJS code: padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding.

If this is not done, the CryptoJS implementation interprets the last byte of the decrypted data as PKCS#7 padding byte  and removes by mistake the number of bytes specified by the padding byte, so that parts of the decrypted data are truncated.

@Topaco, thank you! it solved it. I think i must read more about this modes and padding
